# How do I make a directory writable for the webserver?

Tags: permissions

Just got SQLite up and running on a new linode - but I couldn't make it work til I read some info that says the server must have write permissions for both the directory and the file -- okay fine.

So I made the directory 0777 permissions -- which is probably bad. How do I go about doing this properly?

Comment: What distro are you running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, give ownership of that folder to the to the user the webserver is running as.  (usually "nobody").  `chown <user> <folder>` is the command to do that.  Then, only the first trio of permissions is useful.  So 700 permissions would alow the webuser to access and write to the directory, and no one else to even read it.

--Christopher karel

Comment: Web server on unbuntu apparently runs as 'www-data' -- although I think I remember 'nobody' being the user/group on Solaris. Thanks for the help!